# how can i set ajax response data as a global variable?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to use ajax response as a global variable. It couldn't be used outside 0f success statement. So,

here's my code:

```
 <script>
    var id = $('#@Model.Id').val();
    var connectionData;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@CustomUrl.SendConnectionTime(@Model.Id)',
        data: id,
        success: function(response2) {
            connectionData = response2;
        },
        error: function () {
            alertify.set('notifier', 'position', 'bottom-right');
            alertify.error("Veri g&#246ndermede hata olu&#351;tu.");
        }
    });
</script>
```

and I want to use connectionData in another component like:

```
var myChart = new Chart(canvas,
                    {
                        type: 'line',
                        data: {
                            labels: times,
                            datasets: [
                                {
                                    label: dataConnectionTitle,
                                    data: connectionData,
                                    backgroundColor: [
                                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                                    ],
                                    borderWidth: 1
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        options: {
                            scales: {
                                yAxes: [
                                    {
                                        ticks: {
                                            beginAtZero: true
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
            },
        error: function() {
            alertify.set('notifier', 'position', 'bottom-right');
            alertify.error("Veri g&#246ndermede hata olu&#351;tu.");
        }
    });
```

but when I'm debugging connectionData seems undefined.

Comment: In summary: wrap your `var myChart = new Chart(canvas,` in a function and call that function from your first ajax call's `success:`

Comment: it is solved by adding async:true, field to ajax.